# Linker Command Failed with exite code 1

Tags: xcode, linker-errors

I need some help with this I cannot find a way to fix.

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib/Chartboost'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/rolandmarlow/Dropbox/Business/App/Source'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LCode/Casino/Party'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LSlots/Double'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LDiamond/simpleslots/lib/applovin'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib/ /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib /Users/rolandmarlow/Documents /Users/rolandmarlow/Documents /Users/rolandmarlow/Documents /Users/rolandmarlow/Documents /Users/rolandmarlow/Dropbox/Business/App/Source Code/Casino/Party Slots/Double Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/rolandmarlow/Dropbox/Business/App/Source Code/Casino/Party Slots/Slots Inferno/Inferno Updated/simpleslots/lib /Users/rolandmarlow/Dropbox/Business/App/Source Code/Casino/Party Slots/Slots Inferno/Inferno Updated/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/rolandmarlow/Dropbox/Business/App/Source Code/Casino/Party Slots/Lucky 7s/simpleslots/lib /Users/rolandmarlow/Dropbox/Business/App/Source Code/Casino/Party Slots/Lucky 7s/simpleslots/lib /Users/rolandmarlow/Dropbox/Business/App/Source Code/Casino/Party Slots/Lucky 7s/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/Admin/Desktop/Double Diamond copy/simpleslots/lib /Users/Admin/Desktop/Double Diamond copy/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/SimpleSlots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib /Users/DarielMartinez/Downloads/Triple Diamond/simpleslots/lib'
ld: framework not found HeyzapAds
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to link against one of HeyzapAds' dependencies. Try linking against `libbz2.tbd` and/or `libz.tbd` in your Xcode project, under the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section.